# EHCache Automatic peer discovery on different environments

Tags: ehcache

What's the requested configuration to avoid different environments to share the same cache data in an automatic multicast EHCache configuration ?

I have a test and a prod environment and the cache names are identical, so I presume that if I don't modify the ehcache configuration the prod data will be cached in the test environment too ?

Is a modification of the multiCastGroupAddress is enough to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

But, I guess (hope?) the test and prod machines are located in different subnets, so even having the same `multiCastGroupAddress` would work because the default `timeToLive` is `1` (= multicast is restricted to the same subnet). Please refer the [Ehcache docs on RMI Replicated Caching](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.5/replication/rmi-replicated-caching) for more information.